# Swift Getting Index Out of Range Error While reading Data From Firestore

Tags: swift, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore, swift5

I am trying to pull image data from Firestore and update the UI by adding the images to tableView cells.

However, I am getting Index out of Range error. I believe it's because of the timing issue.

Can you please help me to fix that?

Thanks in advance.

Fatal error: Index out of range: file Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift, line 444

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    createBubbleView()
    getDataFromFireStore()
    
    detailsTableView.delegate = self
    detailsTableView.dataSource = self

    // MARK: - NIB REGISTRATION
    detailsTableView.register(UINib(nibName: K.ingredientsNibName, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: K.ingredientsCell)
    detailsTableView.register(UINib(nibName: K.stepsNibName, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: K.stepsCell)
    detailsTableView.register(UINib(nibName: K.recipeNameNib, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: K.recipeNameCell) }

    

  func getDataFromFireStore() {
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
for ingredient in ingredients {
        db.collection("Ingredients").whereField("name", isEqualTo: ingredient)
            .getDocuments() { [self] (querySnapshot, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    
                    print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                } else {
                    for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                        print(document.get("image")!)
                        if let imageURLsDB = document.get("image") as? [String] {

                            ingredientsImageURLs.append(document.get("image") as! String)
                            
                        }
                        
                        
                    }
            }
            }
    }
    

 // MARK: - RETURNS THE VALUE OF EACH CELL IN THE TABLEVIEW
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = detailsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: K.ingredientsCell)
    switch indexPath.section {
    //        RECIPE NAME
    case 0:
        let cell = detailsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: K.recipeNameCell) as! RecipeTitleCell
        cell.cookingTimeLabel.text = cookingTime
        cell.numberOfIngredientsLabel.text = String(ingredients.count)
        
        return cell
        
    //        INGREDIENTS
    case 1:
        let cell = detailsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: K.ingredientsCell) as! IngredientsCell
        
        cell.ingredientName.text = ingredients[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"Mulish-regular", size:12)
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            cell.ingredientImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: self.ingredientsImageURLs[indexPath.row]), placeholderImage: UIImage(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up"))
            self.detailsTableView.reloadData()
            
        }
        
        
        return cell
```

Comment: On what line do you get the error? What does the row count and section count methods look like and how are the `ingredients` and `ingredientsImageURLs` arrays kept in synch?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, I am getting an error when I try to display the images in ingredientImage cell. You can see the line below;

            cell.ingredientImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: self.ingredientsImageURLs[indexPath.row]), placeholderImage: UIImage(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up"))

Comment: Then perhaps you should also answer my other questions.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, sorry. 

Please see the screenshot here -
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q3md__tZ7tONUsH_e_H6G63SRFUXZQjw/view?usp=drivesdk

ingredients and ingredientsImageURLs have the same amount of elements in firestore. 

However, when I debug, I see 0 elements in ingredientsImageURLs

Comment: My guess is that the code where the crash occurs is called before some (or all) of the elements in ingredientsImageURLs have been downloaded in the getDataFromFireStore function. Best way to avoid this is probably to use one array instead of two.

Comment: I debug the issue but it looks like first  `cell.ingredientImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: self.ingredientsImageURLs[indexPath.row]), placeholderImage: UIImage(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up"))` is being executed before pulling the data from Firestore.I think the question becomes how can I make sure that It won't be executed before I have the data ready.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, guys for the input. That's how I fixed it.

1. Set the images to cells after having the right amount of data

   ```
   if ingredientsImageURLs.count ==  ingredients.count {
           cell.ingredientImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: self.ingredientsImageURLs[indexPath.row]), placeholderImage: UIImage(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up"))
       }
   ```
2. Reload the data after all the images ve been downloaded.

   func getDataFromFireStore() {

   ```
   let db = Firestore.firestore()

   let recipeDocRef = db.collection("Recipes").document(selectedRecipeID).addSnapshotListener { [self] (snapshot, error) in

       if let titleDB = snapshot?.get("title") as? String {
           self.recipeTitle = titleDB
           titleLabel.text = recipeTitle
       }

       if let ingredientsDB = snapshot?.get("ingredients") as? [String] {
           self.ingredients = ingredientsDB
       }

       if let cookingTimeDB = snapshot?.get("cookingTime") as? String {
           self.cookingTime = cookingTimeDB
       }

       if let imageUrlDB = snapshot?.get("imageUrl") as? String {
           self.imageUrl = imageUrlDB
           recipeImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up"))

       }

       if let cookingStepsDB = snapshot?.get("cookingSteps") as? [String] {
           self.steps = cookingStepsDB
       }

       if let stepImagesDB = snapshot?.get("stepImages")  as? [String]{
           self.stepsImages = stepImagesDB
       }

       for ingredient in self.ingredients {
           db.collection("Ingredients").whereField("name", isEqualTo: ingredient)
               .getDocuments()
               { [self] (querySnapshot, err) in
                   if let err = err {

                       print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                   } else {
                       for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                           ingredientsImageURLs.append(document.get("image") as! String)
                       }
                       self.detailsTableView.reloadData()

                   }
               }
           self.detailsTableView.reloadData()
       }

   }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

```
if let imageURLsDB = document.get("image") as? [String] {

   ingredientsImageURLs.append(document.get("image") as! String)
                        
}
```

You check document.get("image") as String array but when you add to your array you check as String.

Comment: Updated it but unfortunately, it did not solve it.

Comment: When you add data to ingredients?

Comment: It's already in the db. It's just pulling that data.

Comment: Please can you share all code of viewcontroller with me? You can add to drive.

Answer (score 0):

Your are calling backend for image and then reloadData, so it calling in every time, setting image non stop. You can't call reload data inside cellForRow, because it will call table view delegates repeatedly.

```
private func getImages()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        cell.ingredientImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:self.ingredientsImageURLs[indexPath.row]), placeholderImage: UIImage(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up"))
        self.imageArray = imagesFromFireStore
        self.detailsTableView.reloadData()
    }
```

// you can put you code here

```
if let imageURLsDB = document.get("image") as? [String] {
                        ingredientsImageURLs.append(document.get("image") as! String)
      //       here just append images to array and call
      self.reloadData()
  }
```

In table view use your imageArray[indexPath.row]

Comment: You are right. I updated that section. However, tableView cellForRow is still being executed before pulling the data from Firestore. How can I populate the images after I have the data ready from Firestore?

Comment: create empty array of images in controller, than create a func that calls images, populate array when data come to you, and in that function call reload data.
I just edited answer up, of course you won't be call it with index path row, use for each or something.